# Which D3JS data chart is most similar to a scheduler?

Tags: info-visualisation, data, javascript, charts

*I realize this is a borderline SO question.*  I am trying to figure out which of [the examples on D3JS](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) most closely resembles a scheduler or Gantt chart so I can use it in our app.

I think bullet charts or box plots are closest.

[image: Box Plots example]

[image: Bullet Charts example]

Any other ideas?

Comment: If you're looking for something similar to a Gantt chart, why doesn't using a Gantt chart work? http://bl.ocks.org/dk8996/5449641

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey thanks for finding that! I didn't see it. put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3.JS does not have built in visualization types. If something doesn't exist you can always create it, and if something doesn't do exactly what you want to do it can be modified. You don't want to pick something that is "close enough" -- if a user is expecting a Gantt chart, a bullet chart (for example) will only cause confusion.

If the visualization you're looking for doesn't have an example, start playing with package to get the data looking the way you want!

There are a few Gantt chart specific examples already on the D3 website:

- http://bl.ocks.org/dk8996/5449641
- http://bl.ocks.org/dk8996/5534835
- http://bl.ocks.org/dk8996/5538271

All are exampled here:

http://dk8996.github.io/Gantt-Chart/

Comment: I am the author of the library and came here to mention it but looks like you beat me to it.